File ended while scanning use of \next. Exam format
I have a problem in my LaTeX file that I wasn't able to solve with my google-fu. Most answers to the same error say that \end{frame} may not be indented. I do not use \end{frame}.
My goal
I want to define an environment called "reponse". Rendering the text it contains should be optional, depending on a global parameter. To this effect, I have opted to use the package "tagging" for its flexibility and ease of use.
The issue
Rendering the optional text works, hiding it throws the error. I compile using pdflatex.
You show the optional block by having \usetag{instructeur} in the preamble, you hide it by having \usetag{whatever_else}. See the following MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{tagging}
\newenvironment{reponse}[0]{\begin{taggedblock}{instructeur}}{\end{taggedblock}}

\usetag{instructeur}


\begin{document}

This is normal text, always displayed.

\begin{reponse}
This text should only be displayed if we do \texttt{\textbackslash usetag\{instructeur\}} in the preamble.
It should disappear if we remove \texttt{instructeur}, but throws and error instead.
\end{reponse}

\end{document}

I should add that tagging on its own works fine, it only breaks when I put it as the begin and end commands of my environment.
Please do not provide a solution that uses a different package, such as "answers". I want to use "tagging" and I believe what I am trying to achive is quite doable.
Thanks in advance!

\newenvironment{reponse}{\taggedblock{instructeur}}{\endtaggedblock} might do the trick (I can't test now).

@campa, interesting. Is this an error in the package manual?

I don't think the package manual suggests wrapping environment that way. It is always  safer to use the internal forms when wrapping environments.

@campa 's answer works.
Using \taggedblock{instructeur} and \endtaggedblock does indeed compile without errors, producing the desired output.
Why then does the official manual not mention the \taggedblock and \endtaggedblock syntax?
Manual foud at CTAN

You can't really ask "why" as the author died, however it is essentially a verbatim/comment environment and the restriction is common to all such environments that they can not usually be nested in another macro.

Oh I did not know. Thanks for the information
